# Vue multiple components shown dependant on store value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a registration form which is shown if the form has not been submitted

```
<template> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <form class="register" v-if="!this.submitted"></form>
        <RegisterSuccess v-if="this.submitted" email="this.form.email"/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import RequestSuccess from './RequestSuccess';
    export default {
        name: 'Request Access',
        components : {
            RequestSuccess
        },
        data(router) {
            return {
                form : {
                    firstname : '',
                    surname : '',
                    email : '',
                    school : '',
                    position : ''
                },
                err : {},
                hasError : false,
                loading : false,
                submitted : false
            }
        }
    }
```

However I am getting the following error,

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.
>
> found in
>
> ---> 
>           at resources/js/components/RequestAccess.vue
>             at resources/js/components/App.vue

Comment: Is that `RegisterSuccess` component globally registered? Otherwise I think you need to add it to your `components: { }`

Comment: @HusamIbrahim edited to how it should actually have been, previously the code was inaccurate.

Comment: The component's name in your template is `RegisterSuccess`

Comment: @HusamIbrahim actually code added

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something here @Udders. I can see you're using `RegisterSuccess` in your template but then you're importing and registering `RequestSuccess` in your script. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Udders Please share the source codes for the component= **RequestSuccess**.